# Trigger a component function from a vuex action/mutation

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

**Short version:** (Im using options API in vue CLI 3)

How can I call a function or execute some code inside a component (in my case `resetModal()`), when something inside my vuex store is triggered (in my case when modal data changes, AKA a new modal is set).

So I want to call `myFunction()` in my component:

```
methods: {
  myFunction() {
    something();
  },
}
```

When a mutation in my store is called:

```
mutations: {
  changeValue() {
    [something to call `myFunction` with];
  },
}
```

**Long version:**

I have a modal component, which is used in my `App.vue` file, (`<modal-bottom v-if="modalBottomInfo.show"></modal-bottom>`) and as you can see it activates whenever the `.show` is true, which is stored in my store, therefore can be activated/deactivated from the entire project.

So far so good, but the problem is, I want to trigger some code whenever a new modal is called, originally I'd done with `mounted() {...}` function inside the modal component, but this way, if a new value for modal is set while its active (`.show` is `true`) the values do change (so changes happen, but the function inside `mounted()` is omitted.

I also tried `updated()` but since my modal has a counter on it, the dom keeps changing so `updated()` is unreliable.

Modal values can only be changed by a mutation in my store, so if there is a way to trigger my function (which is used in `mounted()` inside the same mutation, my problem is solved).

I have also thought of using `watcher:` or moving the entire logic of my modal component to vuex but I dont wanna commit to either without being sure no better way exists yet.

Comment: I think if the logic of ```myFunction()``` is not specific to a component or view and may be called or use in some other components, it is a good idea to  move the entire logic to your ```vuex```. For example you can define a new ```mutation``` for that.

Comment: @hamid-davodi it is specific to the component, I can move the entire logic of the component to store but that wasnt the question here.

Comment: I think updating your question and showing some real and clear code instead of ```something()``` and ... could help you get better answers. Stack overflow does not limit you. You can post the entire component code in the question if it could help to have a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

In your vuex store, you will use a boolean in your state.
When your action is called, you can modify this state boolean.
In your component, you set a computed property with a store getter for this boolean.
You then use it locally to show/hide your modal

Comment: The problem isnt to show/hide the modal, it is already been done as Ive shown by this piece of code `<modal-bottom v-if="modalBottomInfo.show"></modal-bottom>`. it is to execute some code inside the modal component, while its active and its value change, like resetting a timer or showing a pop-up animation, which can be done with mounted but not when a modal overwrites the existing one, in which case only the values inside the component change.